# ManipulationCompleted event is not firing on Button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Application, I have a `ListView` with a button in the `ItemTemplate`, and I need to see when that button's `ManipulationStarted` and `ManipulationCompleted` events are fired. Currently `ManipulationStarted` works fine, but `ManipulationCompleted` does not. Could someone help explain why?

SnapsPage.xaml

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#88686868">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="130" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Manager.Account.Username, FallbackValue='loading...'}" Margin="0,12,0,0" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Snaps" Text="SNAPS" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  Padding="0,0,0,20" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Manager.Account.Snaps}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="ButtonSnap" Style="{StaticResource BasicEmptyButtonStyle}"
                            ManipulationStarting="ButtonSnap_OnManipulationStarting"
                            ManipulationCompleted="ButtonSnap_OnManipulationCompleted"
                            ManipulationMode="All"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControl, Path=DataContext.TryDownloadMediaCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">

                        <!-- Content Here -->

                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MediaGrid" Background="#FF000000" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Image x:Name="MediaImage" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

    <Grid Width="45" Height="45" Background="#99000000"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="25">
        <TextBlock Text="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontSize="24" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

SnapsPage.cs

```
    private void ButtonSnap_OnManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ButtonSnap_OnManipulationStarting");
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button == null) return;
        var snap = button.DataContext as Snap;
        if (snap == null) return;
        _relevantSnap = snap;

        _isFingerDown = true;
        _scrollYIndex = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        _holdingTimer.Start();
    }

    private void ButtonSnap_OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ButtonSnap_OnManipulationCompleted");
        _isFingerDown = false;

        if (_isMediaOpen)
            DisposeMediaTidily();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I tested with Windows Phone 8.1 XAML App (not Silverlight)

The Button has a ManipulationMode of System which, according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationstarted.aspx), means that you should not get manipulation events.

> An element must have a ManipulationMode value other than None or System to be a manipulation event source

Comment: I'll have a go with this and report back later on. (also not using Silverlight)